# ReactJS Ant Design - Disable dates less than any default date in DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Working on [antd framework](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/), I am trying to disable the **DatePicker** date which are less than given defaultDate, I am not able to get it right by any means. The situation is say defaultDate of the Date Picker is **2028-12-20** all dates should be disabled below this..

The callback to do this is as follows

```
disabledDate = (current) => {
    return current && current < moment().endOf('day');;
}
```

where **current = defaultDate** which has been provided it doesn't change, I am not sure how to do this..

I have create a SandBox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx27m9pm0o)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this please https://codesandbox.io/s/p34o4v7wlj , is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @EugeneDzhevadov If the currentDate or defaultDate is `Today` it works fine to me similar to , but if the defaultDate is something like in future as in my example I fail to achieve it.

Comment: I've updated an example https://codesandbox.io/s/p34o4v7wlj

Comment: @EugeneDzhevadov It has disabled all the dates now..

Comment: So, `current` is passed from the component, my guess is that it is always today, but you can define a `default` value instead of `current` and do any logic more, less or equal, but I see the component display today date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done in following way:

```
disabledDate(current) {
  let customDate = "2018-11-25";
  return current && current < moment(customDate, "YYYY-MM-DD");
}
```

Here is the [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nn6r111p0p)

Comment: Great this seems to be working fine, I was calling the moment wrong way.. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Than You, but i need in calendar date should be enabled only 7 days before current date

Comment: current && current > moment() to disable future dates ;)

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you can disable date with enable your available date range / slot.

```
npm install date-fns
```

Package for add or sub days.

```
import {subDays, addDays } from 'date-fns'
```

> Final code

```
<DatePicker 
disabledDate={d => !d || d.isAfter(addDays( new Date(), 7)) || d.isSameOrBefore(subDays( new Date(), 1)) }/>
```

Hope it's helpful.