# Disable all dates before today - Ant Design Calendar

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

I am using Ant Design Calendar in my React project and I want to disable all the dates before today so that the user cannot select it.

The Calendar component looks like -

```
<Calendar
  fullscreen={false}
  onPanelChange={this._onPanelChange}
  onSelect={this._onDateSelect}
  disabledDate={() => }
/>
```

The Calendar API says we need to add `disabledDate` (which returns a boolean) in order to specify that using `momentjs`.

What should the query look like in moment.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444495/reactjs-ant-design-disable-dates-less-than-any-default-date-in-datepicker/53445679) answer your question ?

Comment: The demo doesn't seem to work. I can still select previous dates

Comment: Check [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-beaver-fl6hw) is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use `disabledDate` in `rangePicker` .

```
 disabledDate={(current) => {
return 
   current && current && current < moment().subtract(1, "days") || 
    current >= moment(Date.now()).add(rangepickerlimitmonth, 'month');
                      }}
```

tell me to delete this answer if doesn't work.

`rangepickerlimitmonth`is a number I used to limit date in future which user can't select.